# Combine three duplicate same columns name into one column name that has data from each of the columns respectively

Tags: python, pandas

I had downloaded each individual datasets and used pd.concat to combine each individual datasets into one combined dataframe. However, there are 3 columns that mean the same things but just had different names, so I rename it to have same column name. The problem that I'm now facing is that how to combined 3 same column names with each of its own data into 1 column name with the 'NaN' replacing with value from its column.

The combined dataframe that used `pd.concat` to combine into one df without modifying:

[image: screenshot of combined dataframe]

I used `combinedDF.rename` to change the #YY, YYYY, YY into 'Year':

[image: screenshot of attempt of using rename]

And each of it has value in it, and I am stuck on how to combine 3 columns 'Year' into 1 column 'Year' with NaN having/replacing values from each column.

[image: another screenshot]

I had tried a lot of ways, e.g. using `combinedDF = combinedDF.loc[:,~df.columns.duplicated()].copy()`; `combinedDF.groupby(by="Year").sum()`, etc. but it didn't succeed. How should I do it? Or did I do anything incorrect?

Comment: Why not making the problem less complicated (and your data less ambiguous) by not using the same name for the three columns?

Comment: just use `pandas.DataFrame.drop()` to drop the unwanted columns...  here is the link: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html